# copy files from subfolders using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that copies all `*.r02` files from subfolders and put them in the current folder and rename them to avoid overwriting.
Not sure why the following code doesn't work?

```
@echo off

set Current_Dir = %cd%
For /r %%a in (*.r02) do (
       set /a "counter+=1"
       COPY "%%a" "%Current_Dir%\_%counter%"
)
```

Comment: besides delayed expansion, you have another failure: `set Current_Dir = %cd%` sets a variable `%Current_Dir %`. Remove the spaces on both sides of the `=`

Comment: …and besides that, why create an eleven character variable containing exactly the same value as an already existing two character variable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments @Stephan. I changed the batch file accordingly and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @echo off
   for /r %%a in (*.r02) do (
          set a/ "counter+=1"   
          COPY "%%a" "%cd%\_%counter%"
)

Comment: All Sorted. the following link is helpful "https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23432479/How-to-increment-counter-variable-in-DOS-batch-file.html". Many thanks.